# Add another item to array associative in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-push

im having some issues adding a new item to an associative array,

This is how i'm creating my structure:

```
$cpdata[$count] = array(
  'value' => $value->value,
  'images' => array(
    'color' => $value->color,
    'image' => $value->image,
  ),
);
```

and this is how it looks like when i output like a json:

```
{
  "value": "BOX",
  "images": {
    "color": "white",
    "image": "white.png"
  }
}
```

But i would like to add more items to `images` somthing like this:

```
{
  "value": "BOX",
  "images": [
    {
        "color": "white",
        "image": "white.png"
    },
    {
      "color": "black",
      "image": "black.png"
    },
    {
      "color": "gray",
      "image": "gray.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried with `array_push` and `array_merge` but i cant get it
i've tried `array_push($cpdata['images'][$count]['images'], 'color'=>'red', image' => 'red.png')`

Could you please help me?
Regards
Mario

Answer (score 0):

In context of PHP, what you have there is a JSON variable. If that is coming to you as a string you'll have to decode it first using `json_decode($string);`

Then you can set up an object, populate it with the image variables and write it back to the `$json` object as an array, like:

```
<?php
// example code

$json = <<<EOT
{
  "value": "BOX",
  "images": {
    "color": "white",
    "image": "white.png"
  }
}
EOT;

$json = json_decode($json);
$i = new stdClass;
$i->color = $json->images->color;
$i->image = $json->images->image;
$json->images = array($i);
```

After that you can push to it like

```
$newimage = new stdClass;
$newimage->color = "foo";
$newimage->image = "bar";
$json->images[] = $newimage;
```

output

```
print_r($json);

stdClass Object
(
    [value] => BOX
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [color] => white
                    [image] => white.png
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [color] => foo
                    [image] => bar
                )
        )
)
```

example https://www.tehplayground.com/oBS1SN1ze1DsVmIn

Comment: Hi @Kinglish thank you for your help, but that data comes from a string var and after that i print it like a json, so i'm gonna try that if it works, thank you

Comment: @mxr10 - Did this help solve your question? If so, please accept as the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before converting into json

```
$cpdata[$count] = array(
  'value' => $value->value,
  'images' => array(
    'color' => $value->color,
    'image' => $value->image,
  ),
);
// Cpdata array has $count which has `images` as an array and we want to push another element(array) into images array
array_push($cpdata[$count]['images'], ['color'=>'red', 'image' => 'red.png']);
```

Answer (score 0):

add more items to the "images" array, you should initialize it as an array and then use [ ]  to append new items.

`$cpdata[$count]['images'][]` essentially appends a new associative array to the "images" array associated with the element at index `$count` in the `$cpdata` array

```
// Assuming $value is an object with properties value, color, and image

$value = (object) array('value' => 'BOX', 'color' => 'white', 'image' => 'white.png');

$cpdata = array();
$count = 0;

$cpdata[$count] = array(
    'value' => $value->value,
    'images' => array(
        array('color' => $value->color, 'image' => $value->image)
    ),
);

// Adding more items to the "images" array
$cpdata[$count]['images'][] = array('color' => 'black', 'image' => 'black.png');
$cpdata[$count]['images'][] = array('color' => 'gray', 'image' => 'gray.png');

// Print the result as JSON
echo json_encode($cpdata, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` is a flag used JSON output in a human-readable way